# What happened to Adam Warlock on Counter-Earth?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-3

In *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3*, our heroes fly to Counter-Earth to collect the secret code that should enable them to heal their friend Rocket. Adam Warlock arrives in their wake, hoping to apprehend them and thus save his people, "The Sovereign", from the wrath of the High Evolutionary. Before he can get much involved, he is blown up (calling out "mother!") and restrained.

I think I blinked. Who attacked him?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adam Warlock is caught in one of the explosions that the High Evolutionary is using to eradicate the batch of lifeforms he populated Counter-Earth with. This same explosion destroys the ship with the High Priestess of The Sovereign.

Adam is thrown by the explosion back onto the Guardians' ship and passes out in front of Gamora. At some point, off-screen, she must have dragged him into the ship and restrained him.

Comment: leaves me with a number of questions, but I guess that fits what I remember of that part of the film.

Comment: What questions? If the answer can be made better by clarifying what you think is missing, you should ask them.